# Computer hard drive is full and Macbook doesn't always recognize external drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, macbook, connection

The issue I'm having is that my computer is out of disk space:

- I have roughly 400GB worth of photos and growing. Even if I cleared some space from the hard drive on my Macbook, I wouldn't have enough to hold everything.
- I purchased a Seagate external hard drive that I plug in whenever I want to edit with Elements. However, the computer doesn't always recognize the drive when I plug it in. The last few times, it took nearly 20 minutes of unplugging, waiting, and replugging before being recognized.
- I have been told that using a cloud source is an alternative to external drives. The problem with this is that much of my editing time is done on the go, i.e. outside of my wifi connection. It would kill my data to move 20MB+ files back and forth.
- I asked a computer technician if Macbook hard drives can be replaced as easily as those on PC's (all files mirrored, easy installment, etc.) and was told that it's pretty difficult on a Mac, and many places wouldn't try.

Is there an obvious solution to my problem? Has anyone else dealt with this issue? Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you need all the files on your mac, all the time?

Ideally you need a separate question for this, asking why your hdd doesn't work every time. If it did, you wouldn't have this issue right?

Comment: @djsmiley2k  No, all files aren't necessary, but even if I deleted everything there would not be enough room. I originally asked this question in the photography community but was told to post here since it's more of a computer based issue. I thought it would be somewhat common for photographers, hence included the context. Make sense?

Comment: Do you have a VM running on that machine? (linux/windows) VMS can sometimes grab the disk before the host and then the host won't be able to mount the volume.

Comment: @Yorik No, not running a VM

Answer (score 0):

No note of the type of Macbook (some drives are easy, some are hard to replace).

1. Find the model in Apple menu | About
2. Google for replace HDD for that model

If it's easy enough to replace HDD:

1. Backup Mac using Time Machine
2. Install New HDD/SSD
3. Install MacOS from bootable recovery drive
4. Restore from Time Machine backup

Answer (score 0):

How old is your Macbook? It is fairly easy to replace hard drives (or swap the optical drive for an additional hard disk) in all but the latest Macbooks.

I have replaced hard disks in hundreds of pre-2013 Macbooks and, recently swapped the optical drive on my Early-2011 Macbook Pro with an SSD just last month.

You only need a good toolkit for the specific screws that Apple uses. These kits are cheap - you can pick one for less than $10.

iFixit has several guides that you can use, for example: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Dual+Hard+Drive/13787

Find the one relevant to your model and speed your system up. I hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is the external drive USB or what? If USB and it doesn't have a separated power supply there may nit be enough power on the USB buss that you're pluggimg it into, for instance if you also have a mouse or keyboard, attached.

Comment: It's USB and the only thing plugged into the computer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools on the Mac that can provide some information that would help. The simplest is the "About this Mac" item in the Apple menu. From it you can get a system report which will show you what is connected to the USB ports. The Disk Utility app can help you determine if the drive is recognized, and the Console app can display error messages that may be useful. Have the Console app window open and in front when you plug the external drive in a watch for messages. I assume you never unplug the external drive without ejecting it first.